# Introductory exercise of category theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, functors

> A functor between two preorders is a function $T $ that is monotonic (i.e.,  $p\le p' $ implies $Tp\le Tp' $).

This is an exercise from *Categories for the working mathematician*, (number 1.3.3) whose question is not very clear to me. If we have two preorders, isn't the sentence above a consequence of the definition of functor? Suppose we have an arrow $f : p\to p'$ in the preorder $A $; then $Tf $ is by definition an arrow $Tp\to Tp'$, and since $B $ is a preorder we have $Tp\le Tp'$. I don't think this is what the exercise suppose me to do, but I just don't get it. Thanks for any clarify

Comment: I believe that's all you're supposed to do, actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've just discovered that "exercises" at least in the very beginnings of category theory tend not to be very exercising: you work through the relevant definitions and bingo!